# Заполнение полей таблицы по индивидуальному номеру из ячейки БД

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Здравствуйте друзья! Есть такая вот БД:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И есть такая таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица генерируется в цикле и должна по моей задумке заполнять в процессе генерации ячейки по совпадению цифры с цифрой из id_cell базы данных, но кроме заполнения первой ячейки, больше ничего не происходит:

```
<?php

include 'config/database.php';

// select all data
$query = "SELECT * FROM main_usage";
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();

// this is how to get number of rows returned
#$num = $stmt->rowCount();

$t = 0;
$bg = 0;
for($i=0;$i<35;$i++){
    if($bg < 5){
        $bgr = 'fff';
    }else{
        $bgr = 'ccc';
    }
    ?>

    <tr style="background:#<?php echo $bgr; ?>;text-align:center;">

        <?php

        for($j=0;$j<3;$j++){
            $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if( $row['id_cell'] == $t ){ 
            ?>
            <td class="zz1">
                <?php echo $row['id_name'] ?>
            </td>
            <?php
            }else{
                ?><td class="zz1"><? echo $t; ?></td><?
            }
            $t++;
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $bg++;
    if($bg == 10){
        $bg = 0;
    }
}
?>
</table>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, где исправить косяк? Почему таблица не заполняется в цикле по номеру из id_cell? Ведь по коду, если цикл перебирая id_cell наткнулся на порядковый номер $t по идее должен в эту ячейку положить id_name из БД? Спасибо!

Comment: нет, не должен, цикл идёт по порядку: `0-1-2-3...`  и вероятность того, что `$row['id_cell'] == $t` в данный проход по циклу очень маленькая, и я не знаю такой способ вытаскивания данных из базы, по-этому больше не могу сказать ничего, но может поможет сортировка запроса

Comment: @Blacknife Спасибо! Я чувствовал, что что-то здесь не так. ) Не подскажете как лучше в моём случае поступить? Может как то реорганизовать БД или есть какой - то другой классический способ заполнения по номеру данными из БД в процессе генерации таблицы?

Comment: Опиши пожалуйста конкретнее задумку, до сих пор допустим так и не понятно, нужно тебе именно 104 ячейки или столько, сколько данных в базе

Comment: @Blacknife ячейки таблицы на странице нужны все, разумеется те, которые существуют в базе под своим номером в id_cell заполняют себя информацией из ячейки id_name, а те для которых запись в БД отсутствует, либо порядковый номер (как сейчас), либо просто пустую ячейку. Спасибо!

Comment: ну пока ничего в голову не приходит, кроме как делать запрос в БД в самом цикле `$query = "SELECT * FROM main_usage WHERE id_cell = '$t'";`, после чего можно либо выводить данные либо нет, если запрос не дал результатов

Comment: @Blacknife ОГО! Спасибище!!! Это работает! Скажите, а почему с таким опасением? Это, что какой то не этичный способ? Или из за слишком частого обращения к БД?

Comment: да, именно из-за частого обращения, ну это не настолько критично для вашего случая, и в любом случае по мере изучения php вы сами сможете минимизировать потребление ресурсов в вашем коде

Comment: @Blacknife Спасибо Вам! Всех благ!